# ruby kernel method lookup in top level execution environment

Tags: ruby

I understand in top level execution environment, `self` is some predefined object of class `Object`.

```
puts self.class.inspect #=> Object
```

And

```
puts self.class.ancestors.inspect #=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

But, why I can not find method 'puts' like this?

```
puts self.class.instance_methods.include?(:puts) #=> false
```

I expected `true`, because `Kernel` is `included` in `Object`, can someone tell me why it returns `false`?

#### Solved

`puts` is defined as a private instance method in `Kernel`.

```
Kernel.private_instance_methods.include?(:puts)  #=> true
```

I wonder why the ruby core doc has list `puts` in the public instance method list of `Kernel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons is that

```
Kernel.instance_methods.include? :puts #=> false
```

and

```
self.private_methods.include? :puts #=> true
```

I think that `puts` is declared private in `Object`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. `puts` is defined as private instance method in `Kernel`. I wonder why the ruby core doc list `puts` in the public instance method list of `Kernel`.